# Error open file after saving it with storeFile of pysmb

Tags: python, samba, temporary-files, pysmb

I am reading an Excel file (.xlsx) with pysmb.

```
import tempfile 
from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
 
conn = SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, server_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True) 
conn.connect(server_ip, 139) 
file_obj = tempfile.TemporaryFile() 
file_attributes, filesize = conn.retrieveFile(service_name, test.xlsx, file_obj)
```

This step works, I am able to transform the file in pandas.DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel(file_obj)
```

Next, I want to save the file, the file is saved but if I want to open it with Excel, I have an error message "Excel has run into an error"

Here the code to save the file

```
conn.storeFile(service_name, 'test_save.xlsx', file_obj)
file_obj.close()
```

How can I save correctly the file and open it with excel ?

Thank you

I tried with a .txt file file and it is working. An error occurs with .xlsx, .xls and .pdf files. I have also tried without extension, same issue, imossible to open the file.

I would like to save the file with .pdf and .xlsx extension, and open it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution an I will post it here in case someone face a similar issue.

Excel can be save as a binary stream.

```
from io import BytesIO

df = pd.read_excel(file_obj)
output = BytesIO()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='data', index = False)
writer.save()
output.seek(0)
conn.storeFile(service_name, 'test_save.xlsx', output)
```